# How to change default path of wx-config in makefile?

Tags: wxwidgets

I am working on linux server in which wx-widget 2.8 is installed in /usr/local/.
I have installed wxWidgets 2.9.5 in my build directory /home/jacob/. How to change path of wx-config to my build dir in Makefile? The default path of wx-config --prefix is /usr/local

Comment: why do you need that? Just call the appropriate wx-config...

Comment: I am using MPI and i dont have sudo rights on server. I installed wxWdgets in my build dir to make it available for all nodes

Comment: that is OK. how do you use wx-config?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking about how to change the path returned by `/usr/local/bin/wx-config` but this is a wrong way to approach the problem. If you installed wxWidgets under `/home/jacob`, you must now have `/home/jacob/bin/wx-config` -- simply use this one instead, either explicitly, or by putting `/home/jacob/bin` before `/usr/local/bin` in your `PATH`.